# dispatch is not available in connected component

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to call dispatch from a react component that is connect to redux. For whatever reason i'm unable to call `this.props.dispatch` from this component. However the `showPopup` action is working fine in the component?

[Reading the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-dispatch-and-every-field-in-the-global-state) it says that whenever you have the `connect()`, you should be able to call `this.props.dispatch`. Anything I'm missing here?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Actions
import { showPopup } from '../../../actions';

class Channels extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.dispatch); // <- undefined (?)
        return <div>some stuff</div>;
    }
}

export default connect(null, { showPopup })(Channels);
```

**Update 1**

The following makes it work, is there no way to shorten this?

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    let actions = bindActionCreators({ showPopup });
    return { ...actions, dispatch };
}
```

**Update 2**

```
export default connect(null, (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({ showPopup, dispatch }, dispatch))(Channels);
```

Comment: If you do it like you did it in the first example you can simply call `this.props.showPopup(...)` in your component, which will actually create your action and dispatch it. `...` is any arguments your action creator would take. This greatly simplifies things since you don't need to create then manually dispatch the actions.

Comment: @BalázsÉdes I know, but I still need the `dispatch` for another action ;)

Comment: Why not just write an action creator for that as well? You can have as many of these as you want.

Comment: @BalázsÉdes asking a good question, guess I can ;)

Comment: Just add it to the object when you are connecting: `{ showPopup, otherActionCreator }`

Answer (score 1):

Your first code should work just change your `this.props.dispatch` to `this.props.showPopup`.

If you pass a second argument to `connect` method, it will map those actions as props. `connect(null, { showPopup, otherAction, someAction })(Channels);`, you can use `this.props.showPopup()` or `this.props.otherAction` or `this.props.someAction` to dispatch the action

If you just do `connect()(Channels);` then you need to use `this.props.dispatch(showPopup(...))` or `this.props.dispatch(otherAction())` or `this.props.dispatch(someAction())`

Comment: Thanks for this however I am not having difficulties calling the `showPopup`. I need the dispatch to call another action from an imported library.

Comment: Edited my answer to show you dispatching other action. As long as it's returning an action object, you can dispatch it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are defining mapDispatchToProps as an object.

[The documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) says that:

> Your component will no longer receive dispatch as a prop